# How network event FD_WRITE is generated when using Event Driven Sockets?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, events, network-programming

I am working on newtwork event based socket application.

When client has sent some data and there is something to be read on the socket, FD_READ network event is generated.

Now according to my understanding, when server wants to write over the socket, there must be an event generated i.e. FD_WRITE. But how this message will be generated?

When there is something available to be read, FD_READ is automatically generated but what about FD_WRITE when server wants to write something?

Anyone who can help me with this confusion please?

Following is the code snippet:

```
WSAEVENT hEvent = WSACreateEvent();
WSANETWORKEVENTS events;
WSAEventSelect(newSocketIdentifier, hEvent, FD_READ | FD_WRITE);

   while(1)
      {   //while(1) starts
         waitRet = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1, &hEvent, FALSE, WSA_INFINITE, FALSE);
         //WSAResetEvent(hEvent);
         if(WSAEnumNetworkEvents(newSocketIdentifier,hEvent,&events) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
              //Failure
            }
     else
        {   //else event occurred starts
            if(events.lNetworkEvents & FD_READ)
            {
                            //recvfrom()   
            }
            if(events.lNetworkEvents & FD_WRITE)
            {
                 //sendto()
            }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FD_WRITE means you can write to the socket right now.  If the send buffers fill up (you're sending data faster than it can be sent on the network), eventually you won't be able to write anymore until you wait a bit.

Once you make a write that fails due to the buffers being full, this message will be sent to you to let you know you can retry that send.

It's also sent when you first open up the socket to let you know it's there and you can start writing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576(v=vs.85).aspx

> The FD_WRITE network event is handled slightly differently. An
>   FD_WRITE network event is recorded when a socket is first connected
>   with a call to the [connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-connect), [ConnectEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/mswsock/nc-mswsock-lpfn_connectex), [WSAConnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaconnect), [WSAConnectByList](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaconnectbylist),
>   or [WSAConnectByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaconnectbynamea) function or when a socket is accepted with [accept](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-accept),
>   [AcceptEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/mswsock/nf-mswsock-acceptex), or [WSAAccept](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaaccept) function and then after a send fails with
>   [WSAEWOULDBLOCK](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/WinSock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2) and buffer space becomes available. Therefore, an
>   application can assume that sends are possible starting from the first
>   FD_WRITE network event setting and lasting until a send returns
>   WSAEWOULDBLOCK. After such a failure the application will find out
>   that sends are again possible when an FD_WRITE network event is
>   recorded and the associated event object is set.

So, ideally you're probably keeping a flag as to whether it's OK to write, right now.  It starts off as true, but eventually, you get a **WSAEWOULDBLOCK** when calling **sendto**, and you set it to false.  Once you receive **FD_WRITE**, you set the flag back to true and resume sending packets.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but I am using udp sockets where there are no coonect() and accept() :(

Comment: You are still calling sendto.  This can cause the buffers to fill.  After they fill, and then empty out to some extent, you will get this event -- see this part of the paragraph I pasted: after a send fails with WSAEWOULDBLOCK and buffer space becomes available

Comment: I have got some idea still I have confusions. What is the reason of FD_SEND when I am calling sendto() prior to it? Can you share a simple example of how to use FD_WRITE

Comment: you don't "use it".. it's just telling you that while before the socket was full, but it isn't anymore, so you can likely call sendto and it won't send you back an error (WSAEWOULDBLOCK).  Shoot, you can just ignore it completely, but you'll potentially waste a lot of time calling sendto when it cannot succeed.